# aggregating the table using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is the input.

```
            X   Y   Z
AP          1   1   1
Karnataka   0   1   0
Goa         1   1   0
Tamilnadu   0   1   0
AP          0   1   1
Goa         0   0   0
Tamilnadu   0   1   1
Goa         0   0   0
AP          1   0   0
Tamilnadu   0   1   0
Tamilnadu   1   1   0
Goa         0   1   1
Karnataka   0   0   0
Karnataka   0   1   0
```

Calculations to be performed:

1. number of states present in column A
2. number of 1's present in column X divided by count of each state in column A
3. The code should be dynamic,as the number of columns and rows may vary.

Expected output:

```
                   Total      AP   Karnataka    Goa      Tamilnadu
Total Sample        14        3        3         4           4
X                 0.2857    0.6667  0.0000    0.2500      0.2500
Y                 0.7143    0.6667  0.6667    0.5000      1.0000
Z                 0.2857    0.6667  0.0000    0.2500      0.2500
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure there is a better way, but the following works.

Suppose my_df has the input data;

```
result=my_df.groupby('A').mean().transpose()
result1=my_df.groupby('A').sum().transpose()
result1=result1.append(my_df['A'].value_counts())
result1=result1.rename({'A':'Total Sample'})
result1['Total']=result1.apply('sum',axis=1)
finalRow=result1.iloc[len(result1)-1]
for i in range(len(result1)-1):
    result1.iloc[i]=result1.iloc[i]/finalRow
result['Total']=result1['Total']
result=result.append(result1.loc['Total Sample'])
```

Done!!!